# duplicate key after push data from a loop to array

Tags: node.js, typescript

this my request body :

```
{
    "data": [
        {"firstName": "a"}, {"lastName": "b"}
    ]
}
```

this is my script :

```
var body = request.body;
for(var i = 0;i < body.data.length;i++){
 var obj = body.data[i];                                                         
 keyes.push(Object.keys(obj));                                                            
 console.log(keyes);
}
```

i'm trying to push response data from loop to array, and why i'm getting the response like this :

```
[ [ 'firstName' ] ]
[ [ 'firstName' ], [ 'lastName' ] ]
```

i'm wanna the response like this:

```
[ [ 'firstName' ], [ 'lastName' ] ]
```

Thanks before

Comment: Actually, your code does exactly the same thing. you have `[ [ 'firstName' ], [ 'lastName' ] ]` in your `keyes` property after the for loop completed. To verify it - you could move `console.log(keyes)` statement outside for loop.

Comment: could you give full code :)

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: `const keyes = request.body.data.map(Object.keys);`

Comment: @Ahmed your code is right, just bring the console.log out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems you need final output not at every step. 
To do that,you need to print console.log(keyes) outside the loop.

Thanks

Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const keyes = request.body.data.map(Object.keys);
```

it should give you this result `[ [ 'firstName' ], [ 'lastName' ] ]`

> Actually, your code does exactly the same thing. you have `[ [ 'firstName' ], [ 'lastName' ] ]` in your `keyes` property after the for loop completed. To verify it - you could move `console.log(keyes)` statement outside for loop.
>
> And you have a typo in `keyes` variables `keyes => keys`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does exactly the same as required, you just need to place console.log at the correct place. Like this

```
for(var i = 0;i < body.data.length;i++){
 var obj = body.data[i];
 keyes.push(Object.keys(obj));
}
console.log(keyes)
```